# Weird segfault occurence

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
typedef struct  
{
    char path[MAX_FILENAME*MAX_FOLDERS];
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME];
    time_t date;
    off_t size;
} FILES;
```

This code works

```
FILES *fls = (FILES*)malloc(sizeof(FILES));
    strcpy(fls[0].filename, "asd");
    printf("%s\n", fls[0].filename);
    fls = (FILES*)realloc(fls, 2);
    strcpy(fls[1].filename, "asdfgh");
    printf("%s\n", fls[0].filename);
    printf("%s\n", fls[1].filename);
```

But here:

```
void allocateFileTree(FILES *tree,int i)
{
    if(i==0)
      tree = (FILES*)malloc(sizeof(FILES));
    else
      tree = (FILES*)realloc(tree, sizeof(FILES)*i);      

}
```

in a loop

```
allocateFileTree(tree, i);
struct stat buff;
stat(entry -> d_name, &buff);

strcpy(tree[i].path, "whatever");//it gives segfault
i++;//this is never executed so realloc isn't the problem (yet)
```

Why and how can I solve this? What is so different that it crashes?

Comment: What is the declaration of `tree` in your "in a loop" scope? It is apparently a pointer or array. You seem to intend to modify it in `allocateFileTrees()`, but that function modifies only the local pointer value and does not modify the passed-in pointer. That would require a double pointer.

Comment: I've declared tree global and replaced allocateFileTree() with it's code but it still gives segfault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you say works really doesn't. One major problem is this line here

```
fls = (FILES*)realloc(fls, 2);
```

This reallocate the pointer to be two *bytes*. There's also a problem with this if the `realloc` call fails, as then you overwrite the only pointer you have with `NULL`, and therefore loose the original pointer and have a memory leak (besides the obvious problem of dereferencing a `NULL` pointer).

Your exact cause of the crash is because you don't allocate memory for the `path` member, so you're using an uninitialized pointer.

Both of the above leads to *undefined behavior*, which is a common cause of crashes.

And finally, in C you [should not cast the return of `malloc` (and family)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: my mistake path is now [MAX] but the first code works, i think the first comment describes my problem

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu The first piece of code just *seem* to work, in reality you are overwriting memory you haven't allocated. The size given to `realloc` is the number of *bytes* you want to allocate.

Comment: in the second piece of code realloc is correct but I still get segfault! How can I solve this?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu The expression `sizeof(tree)` returns the size of *the pointer*, not the size of the structure.

Comment: changed it to FILES but I have the same problem, anyway it never gets to i++ it crashes at the first appending

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu And you *do* initialize `i` to zero first?

Comment: yes but I had incremented it before and forgot, thanks for the suggestion now it's working

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu There's actually another problem with your code, and I'm surprised it works, because you modify the argument `tree`, but in C all arguments are passed by value (i.e. copied) so you're only modifying the *local copy* of that pointer. The function calling `allocateFileTree` will not see the changes in the `allocateFileTree` function as those are only local in that function.

Answer (score 1):

While you allocate space for an array of FILES, you do not allocate storage for `path` in the code shown.

In the code

```
strcpy(tree[i].path, "whatever")
```

The value of `tree[i].path` is undefined.  It might happen to point to space you can write to, or not.

Comment: my mistake path is now [MAX], copied the wrong code

Comment: but I still get segfault

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
(FILES*)realloc(tree, sizeof(tree)*i);
```

allocates enough space for `i` pointers since `tree` is a `FILES*`.  I think you want:

```
(FILES*)realloc(tree, sizeof(*tree)*i);
```

Your other problem is that you never actually update your tree pointer.  The `allocateFileTree()` function only every updates it's local copy of the pointer to the new allocation.

You may want to try something like

```
FILES* allocateFileTree(FILES *tree,int i)
{
    if(i==0)
      tree = (FILES*)malloc(sizeof(FILES));
    else
      tree = (FILES*)realloc(tree, sizeof(FILES)*i);      

    return tree;
}
```

and call it like so:

```
tree = allocateFileTree(tree, i);
```